# ViewCountLifeTime Management Property

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-property

What is the difference between `ViewCountLifeTime` and `ViewsLifeTime` managed properties ?

Comment: ViewsLifeTime is from sharepoint, where ViewCountLifeTime I think is coming from Graph API. That's my guess

Answer (score 0):

These properties are maintained by SharePoint Analytics and can be used via CSOM or Search Queries.

`ViewCountLifeTime` - This is a special managed property that is not associated with any crawled property. This property shows how many time a document has been viewed on the office web apps.

`ViewsLifeTime` - This property data is updated every 15 days and give you the view count for content (Ex: Page/Site etc)

Comment: PDF documents cannot be viewed on office web apps but still it has ViewCountLifeTime property with some value assigned. Also, ViewCountLifeTime always has value equal or greater than ViewLifeTime. I am not able to clearly distinguish between both of the managed property.

Comment: `ViewLifeTime` is updated every 15 minutes may be that is the reason you are seeing this difference. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to display view count of document in content search webpart, but not able to decide which property(ViewCountLifeTime or ViewLifeTime) should I make use of.

Comment: If you check Delve you can see it uses `ViewCountLifeTime` to display the number of Views of a file..