# Managed Property for counting document views

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-property, modern-experience, sorting

I'm working with a custom search solution on SharePoint Online using the modern experience. I'm hoping to be able to sort the results from this based on the number of views per document (i.e. the documents relative popularity). Is there a managed property i can use to sort on? Or will i have to do a REST call of some sort? Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You can use viewslifetime managed property. Will get you the most read docs

Comment: @Gautam Sheth, how would I create a view that would only show me the most viewed files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like Sheth said, viewslifetime is a useful property. In fact there are a bunch of similar managed properties you can use. 
[image]

A bit more information about viewslifetime and viewcountlifetime:
[ViewCountLifeTime Management Property](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/228888/viewcountlifetime-management-property)