# Most used Files View

Tags: sharepoint-online, view

The goal would be to create a view that only shows the files that have been used the most.
Let’s say the view is showing 100 items that are used quite often from the users.

This would be  really great considering the fact that only a small number of files is being used on the daily basis.

Answer (score 2):

ed, 
For SharePoint Online, a new view is not the best tool to do this. The workaround I think will work better in modern experience is the Highlighted content web part which dynamically display content from a document library, a site, a site collection, or all sites. By default, this web part shows your most recent documents. And you can change it to be sorted by most viewed with filters.
[image]

Check how to use this web part here:https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-highlighted-content-web-part-e34199b0-ff1a-47fb-8f4d-dbcaed329efd#bkmk_filterandsort

Update: The most popular items experience and introduction:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/view-popularity-trends-and-most-popular-items
[image]

Comment: in case we are using the clossic experience. is there a way to create a view what sort by: most viewed ? that would be the best option as if for now. thank you

Comment: @Ed1995 For classic experience, i will recommend using Search Result web part with a customized query and using property concerning number of views to sort. You can have a check on this https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/266531/managed-property-for-counting-document-views/266552#266552

Comment: thank u. The idea is to have a view that only shows the most used fles. why so ? Our docume nt library consist of many items but only a number of them are used  on the daily basis. i would really good but I dont see anything sort by: most viewed when creating a view

Comment: @Ed1995 Per my knowledge it is not doable with only creating a certain view. Another much simpler option is using the Most Popular Items in your library ribbon, it will sort all the files with viewed times.You can sort the list by Recent (views the last 14 days), or Ever (views from the first time the item became available). It is a built-in approach with the same idea of search result web part. But much easier. If you want to limit items shows up, you may need to use your own search result web part

Comment: This doesn't completely fullfill the idea I had in mind because with with views its just much easier for the users especially when u set the view to default. The users just go there see their daily used file and go from there. I appreciate your help

Comment: @Ed1995, The only difference is you will need to click a button on the ribbon. However just as you say there is a bit difference. This is kind of limitation of a list view which you need to use bit more steps.

Comment: how would you use Most Popular items in case you are using the modern expereince ?

Comment: @Ed1995 In modern experience, you just use highlight content instead of Most Popular items.

Comment: @ jerry_MSFT do you have any article of post that tell me more about highlight content ?

Comment: @Ed1995  Some how-to articles you can have a look at:https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-roll-up-content-from-sharepoint-sites-using-highlighted-content-web-part/      https://www.kalmstrom.com/Tips/SharePoint-Online-Course/New-Page-Model-Highlighted.htm