# Showing refined list of subsites via search results web part based on most clicked subsites

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, refiner, search-query

I am working with SharePoint online classic site collection. 
Using a search results web part on a search page, I am displaying a list of subsites using following query:

> (path:https://****.sharepoint.com/asset/ contentclass:"STS_Site") (contentclass:"STS_Web")-title:asset Description:Development OR Description:Transition {SearchBoxQuery}

Its working great (have a custom display template in use too), however I am looking for an improvement. Is there a way to refine the list of site names to appear based on most clicked sites, so as an example, the most clicked should appear first and least clicked to appear last. Is there a way to refine/sort them based on most clicked sites?

Please advise, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a property named viewslifetime. It shall be useful for your requirement. In fact there are a bunch of similar managed properties you can use. enter image description here
[image]

A bit more information about viewslifetime and viewcountlifetime:
[ViewCountLifeTime Management Property](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/228888/viewcountlifetime-management-property)

Comment: Thanks Jerry, upon using above, it says Something went wrong "Sortlist". Not sure if this would help me refresh list of subsites to show based on the most clicked once, thoughts?

Comment: @mdevm In my test it works fine with the viewslifetime both ascending and descending. What kind of error did you meet? Maybe you can do some tests with a new web part or other managed property.